# How to change parameters for tf-idf fit method in python?

Tags: python, pipeline, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am working on tf-idf using pandas pipelines. I am using the `lnc.ltc` weighing scheme from [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_Information_Retrieval_System) notation.

```
query = 'some string'
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', use_idf=False, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=True)),
    ])
doc_vectors = pipeline.fit_transform(data).toarray()
query_vector = pipeline.transform([query]).toarray()
```

For document vectors, I want to set `use_idf=False` which is done. But how do I set `use_idf=True` for query vector?
I tried directly changing the `use_idf` parameter but it does not work.

Comment: Pipeline objects are meant to be static and specific. If it were me, I'd create two different pipelines anyway rather than trying to force a switch, as different data types need to be handled differently (as you've seen)

Comment: Creating 2 difderent pipelines isn't working as I need to use the values learned by fit method in the query vector. Can you tell me how to go forward with this ?

Comment: If you need to use the same object to act in two different ways on two different objects, then maybe it shouldn't be in a pipeline. If this is the full pipeline, then you're not gaining much by using a pipeline object for two actions. Call the vectorizer on it's own, then call two different tfidf transformers with a conditional for that param. As in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341668/the-purpose-of-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline), a pipeline is good for automating the SAME workflow over and over, not different workflows, with no way to add any conditional into it.